# Direction of CSS transition changes when input is focused

Tags: html, css

In the course of trying to animate an input to slide out using CSS, I came across some behaviour which I don't understand and was hoping someone could help me understand. Essentially, the transition runs as I expect so long as the input doesn't gain focus during the transition. However, as soon as focus is gained during the transition, the transition suddenly looks "right-aligned" rather than "left-aligned" as I expect.

Here's a MWE to illustrate what I mean. The following snippet works fine if you don't focus the input too quickly:

```js
let b = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];

b.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.toggle("expanded");
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  
  transition: 1s width ease;
}

.container.expanded {
  width: 22ch;
}

.margin {
  background: green;
  width: 20ch;
}

input {
  margin-left: 2ch;
  width: 20ch;
}
```

```html
<button>Press for magic!</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="margin"><input type="text" value="A quick brown fox..."/></div>
</div>
```

However, if you focus the input quickly enough, you get something like this (screenshot from mid-transition):

[image: bad transition]

Here's what I would expect mid-transition, for contrast:

[image: good transition]

The main difference is that when unfocused, the content reveals left-to-right (which is what I would expect), whereas when focused, the content reveals right-to-left.

Would anyone be able to explain to me why this behaviour occurs? I looked through the user-agent styles on the input in both Chrome and Firefox and didn't see anything which might be causing this. I suspect this stems from my own misunderstanding of how CSS transitions work (or maybe some CSS layout thing), so any help understanding the reasons behind this would be much appreciated!

Let me know if there's anything I should add to this post to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reproduce the issue even without transition. Simply put the input inside a smaller container and focus on it to get the weird but logical result:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container.expanded {
  width: 100px;
}

.margin {
  background: green;
  width: 20ch;
}

input {
  margin-left: 2ch;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container expanded">
  <div class="margin"><input type="text" value="A quick brown fox..."/></div>
</div>
```

Your input is overflowing the container and you are hiding the overflow. If you add the scroll you will better understand

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.container.expanded {
  width: 100px;
}

.margin {
  background: green;
  width: 20ch;
}

input {
  margin-left: 2ch;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container expanded">
  <div class="margin"><input type="text" value="A quick brown fox..."/></div>
</div>
```

Focusing on the input will scroll the container, as simple as that. The only difference is that you are hidding the scroll but this doesn't mean the container cannot be scrolled.

I am not able to find where this behavior is described <sup>1</sup> but it seems an intuitive one for me since we need to show the focused element and in order to do this we need to scroll some elements.

Here is another example with many inputs on the page and you can clearly see that each time we need to scroll to show the next one:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
input {
  margin-left: 2ch;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container expanded">
  <input type="text" value="One"/>
  <input type="text" value="two"/>
  <input type="text" value="three"/>
  <input type="text" value="Four"/>
</div>



  <input type="text" value="five" style="margin-top:200vh"/>
```

<sup>1</sup>: It should be in this part of the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#focus

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and I can verify the behaviour myself. Thanks for teaching me something new!